# Improve postgres view performance

Tags: postgresql

I would like to improve the performance of my Postgres view.
I use this view for reports later on, and I just was not able to make it better till now. I tried limiting the dataset by decreasing it to the actual year and the year before, which made me go from ~120k rows to ~50k rows, but nothing changed on a performance level...

At the moment, a `select * from view;` statement takes ~55s for ~53k rows.

Here's a ddl statement of my view and an explain statement as well.

Dalibo explain: https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/GU1

At the bottom of my post, you can find the DDL for the source tables as well.

Postgres version I currently use: **PostgreSQL 11.13**

**DDL VIEW**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.v_event_executed_methods
AS WITH wf AS (
         SELECT notes.piid,
            notes.wfkommentar,
            notes.wfkommentaranonym,
            pi.processid AS wfprocessid,
            pi.creationdate AS wfcreationdate,
            pi.finishdate AS wfgeschlossen,
            pi.facilityid,
            pi.deviceid,
            pi.description,
            pi.creationdate,
            df.facilityname,
            df.tenantname,
            dd.name AS devicename,
            pi.createdby,
            pi.closedby
           FROM ( SELECT process_notes.piid,
                    string_agg((((process_notes.creationdate || ':'::text) || process_notes.username::text) || ':'::text) || process_notes.content::text, ''::text) AS wfkommentar,
                    string_agg((process_notes.creationdate || ':'::text) || process_notes.content::text, '
'::text) AS wfkommentaranonym
                   FROM process_notes
                  GROUP BY process_notes.piid) notes
             RIGHT JOIN process_information pi ON pi.piid = notes.piid
             JOIN dimfacility df ON pi.facilityid = df.facilityid AND df.scd_active = true
             LEFT JOIN dimdevice dd ON pi.deviceid = dd.deviceid AND dd.scd_active = true
        ), ccnotes AS (
         SELECT hen.eventresultid,
            string_agg((((hen.date || ':'::text) || ((( SELECT du.logonname
                   FROM dimuser du
                  WHERE hen.userid = du.userid
                 LIMIT 1))::text)) || ':'::text) || hen.note::text, '
'::text) AS cckommentar,
            string_agg((hen.date || ':'::text) || hen.note::text, '
'::text) AS cckommentaranonym
           FROM hist_event_note hen
          GROUP BY hen.eventresultid
        )
 SELECT COALESCE(cc.tenantname, wf.tenantname) AS tenantname,
    COALESCE(cc.facilityname, wf.facilityname) AS facilityname,
    COALESCE(cc.devicename, wf.devicename) AS devicename,
    cc.id,
    cc.eventtype,
    to_char(cc.incomingdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)::timestamp without time zone AS incomingdate,
    to_char(cc.occurrencedate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)::timestamp without time zone AS occurrencedate,
    to_char(cc.closingdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)::timestamp without time zone AS closingdate,
    cc.level,
    cc.severity,
    cc.closingstatus,
    cc.eventmethodkey,
    cc.nativeprocessid,
    cc.grund,
    COALESCE(wf.description, cc.beschreibung)::character varying(1600) AS beschreibung,
    cc.logonname,
    cc.executiondate,
    cc.deviceid,
    cc.facilityid,
    cc.executionsucess,
    cc.methodkey,
    cc.methodexecutionid,
    cc.type,
        CASE
            WHEN cc.cckommentar IS NULL THEN ''::text
            ELSE 'CC: '::text || cc.cckommentar
        END AS cckommentar,
    wf.piid,
        CASE
            WHEN wf.wfkommentar IS NULL THEN ''::text
            ELSE 'WF: '::text || wf.wfkommentar
        END AS wfkommentar,
    wf.wfprocessid,
    wf.wfcreationdate,
    wf.wfgeschlossen,
    cc.createdby AS cccreatedby,
    cc.closedby AS cclosedby,
    wf.createdby AS wfcreatedby,
    wf.closedby AS wfclosedby,
    to_char(cc.firstowningdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)::timestamp without time zone AS firstowningdate,
    to_char(COALESCE(cc.occurrencedate, wf.creationdate), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)::timestamp without time zone AS aufgetreten,
    COALESCE(wf.wfprocessid, cc.id::character varying(100)) AS ticketnr,
    to_char(COALESCE(cc.firstowningdate, wf.creationdate, cc.incomingdate), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)::timestamp without time zone AS angenommen,
    cc.parameter,
        CASE
            WHEN wf.wfkommentaranonym IS NULL THEN ''::text
            ELSE 'WF: '::text || wf.wfkommentaranonym
        END AS wfkommentaranonym,
        CASE
            WHEN cc.cckommentaranonym IS NULL THEN ''::text
            ELSE 'CC: '::text || cc.cckommentaranonym
        END AS cckommentaranonym,
        CASE
            WHEN cc.nativeprocessid IS NULL AND wf.wfprocessid IS NULL THEN 'Ereignis'::text
            WHEN cc.id IS NULL THEN 'Servicefall'::text
            ELSE 'Event u. Servicefall'::text
        END AS servicefallevent
   FROM ( SELECT ve.id,
            ve.eventtype,
            ve.incomingdate,
            ve.occurrencedate,
            ve.closingdate,
            ve.level,
            ve.severity,
            ve.closingstatus,
            ve.eventmethodkey,
            ve.devicename,
            ve.tenantname,
            ve.facilityname,
            ve.nativeprocessid,
            ve.grund,
            ve.beschreibung,
            vme.logonname,
            vme.executiondate,
            vme.deviceid,
            vme.facilityid,
            vme.executionsucess,
            vme.methodkey,
            vme.methodexecutionid,
            vme.type,
            cn.cckommentar,
            ve.closedby,
            ve.createdby,
            ve.firstowningdate,
            vme.parameter,
            cn.cckommentaranonym
           FROM v_event ve
             LEFT JOIN v_method_executions vme ON ve.id = vme.eventid
             LEFT JOIN ccnotes cn ON cn.eventresultid = ve.id) cc
     FULL JOIN wf ON wf.wfprocessid::text = cc.nativeprocessid::text
  WHERE date_part('year'::text, cc.occurrencedate) >= date_part('year'::text, CURRENT_DATE - '1 year'::interval);
```

**EXPLAIN**

[Link here - Body too long](https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20211101vpGYWcKK)

**DDL Source Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE public.process_notes (
    pnid int8 NOT NULL,
    piid int8 NULL,
    subject varchar(500) NULL,
    "content" varchar(4000) NULL,
    firstname varchar(200) NULL,
    surename varchar(200) NULL,
    username varchar(80) NULL,
    creationdate timestamp NOT NULL,
    changeddate timestamp NULL,
    CONSTRAINT process_notes_pkey PRIMARY KEY (pnid)
);

CREATE TABLE public.hist_event_note (
    id int8 NOT NULL,
    haschanged bool NULL,
    "date" timestamp NULL,
    note varchar(1024) NULL,
    workingtime int8 NULL,
    eventresultid int8 NULL,
    interventionactivityid int8 NULL,
    userid int8 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT hist_event_note_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE public.process_information (
    piid int8 NOT NULL,
    facilityid int8 NULL,
    deviceid int8 NULL,
    cost_center varchar(4096) NULL,
    description varchar(3000) NULL,
    ordernumber int8 NULL,
    processid varchar(100) NULL,
    creationdate timestamp NOT NULL,
    finishdate timestamp NULL,
    changeddate timestamp NULL,
    createdby varchar(60) NULL,
    closedby varchar(60) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT process_information_pkey PRIMARY KEY (piid)
);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you create a functional index on date_part('year'::text, cc.occurrencedate)  ? That could help. Also, use EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) to get the complet query plan, and you could post it on https://explain.dalibo.com/ to share it with others.

Comment: Hi @FrankHeikens, Thanks for your help! I haven't tried the functional index. That date_part part is just something I added yesterday to see if the performance would increase. The original view does not have it. I just generated the query plan here: https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/GU1

Comment: Your query is too complicated. Consider using a materialized view.